# How Do I link my php Login form to select from a list of usernames and passwords from my database and auntheticate

Tags: php

I have tried linking my php code with mysql database but the form doesnot authenticate to select from the list of names and passwords in the database Below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $us=$_POST['username'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];
       $servername="localhost";
       $username="root";
       $password="root";
       $dbname="rx_group";
       $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
       if($conn->connect_error)
       {
           die("Connection Failed:".$conn->connect_error);
       }
       else{
           echo 'connection succesful';
           $message='Welcome';
       }

       if($us == $sql="select name from users where name=$us"){
           echo '<br><b>You have successfully Logged in</b>';

           //$login=$sql="select from users where password=$pass";
       }
    else
    {
        echo"<br>Wrong Credentials Please Try Again or Signup";

    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
    <form><input type="submit" Value="signup" <a href="signup.php"> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not executing the query.  But you really want to move this over to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Cerad as written, this question doesn't contain enough information in it to be a good migration (or repost) on Stack Overflow. There is no information about what errors are happening, what the expected outcome is, or such.  Glancing at the code, its just... wrong. `if($foo == $sql = "some sql")` - and `<form><input type="submit" Value="signup" <a href="signup.php"> </form>` - there is too much wrong with the code in this question to be properly answerable.

Comment: @Mpairewe, forget about half the problem. Write a program that selects a value from the database and prints that. If you have a question about that, then ask that on Stack Overflow. Write a program that authenticates against hard coded values a user named `user` with a password `password`. If you have a question about *that*, again, ask it on Stack Overflow. Once you are able to do both of those, try putting these two together and write the code you are trying to do so here.

Comment: @MichaelT i actually wanted to post the full code here but it was cut short!,Actually iam trying to create a login page for users who already exist in my database but i have tried executing the select statement in different ways but its failing out and executing only the else statement!

Comment: @MpairweHumphrey that is because the way you think the connection and SQL works, doesn't work that way. Trying to correct that misunderstanding is the subject of entire tutorials out there on the net. You need to start out with something that has fewer moving parts (authentication has many). Write a program that prints out the name of all the users. That's it. No ifs, elses, or other control structures. Make sure you know how to actually connect, query, and read from the database. If you don't know how to do that, authentication against a database is impossibly confusing.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanx 4 the advise!

Comment: @Mpairwe: there's quite a few security issues here, so I'd agree with Michael that using a tutorial is a good idea. Have a look at my profile if you want a step-by-step guide. If you do give it a go, try not to complete it in one sitting - it is rather substantial.